# opencart 2.0 чпу вызов метод контроллера

Tags: php, cms, opencart

Как вызывается метод контролера в opencart 2.0 если чпу включена например есть метод в контроллере `items/items/getDesc` подключил чпу, получилось `product/getDesc` перехожу по `product/getDesc` а там получаю `404` возможно есть какие то параметры при получения ссылки с помощью `$this->url->link('items/items');`

Comment: У метода getDesc есть output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробовали?

```
$this->url->link('items/items/getDesc');
```

Comment: Помогло спасибо.